# Convert xsd:date to xsd:gYear in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

Hello I'm trying to retrieve from DBpedia persons that are born in Lyon after 1900 ("1900"^^xsd:gYear)
Here is my piece of code :

```
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
prefix dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
select $n $birthDate
{
  $p a dbo:Person.
  $p dbo:birthPlace dbr:Lyon.
  $p foaf:name $n.
  $p dbo:birthDate $birthDate.
  filter($birthDate > "1980"^^xsd:gYear).
}
```

And I'm getting the following results : 
[query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yON1d.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, the problem is in the data: many dates do not have valid `xsd:date` literals, thus, the comparison fails. It also fails for `filter($birthDate > "1980-01-01"^^xsd:date)`. According to XML Schema, `xsd:date` must provide the literal in form `"YYYY-MM-DD"`. And that's unfortunately not the case for many dates in DBpedia. For valid dates, the comparison works perfectly.

Workaround:

```
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
prefix dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
select $n $birthDate ?year
{
  $p a dbo:Person.
  $p dbo:birthPlace dbr:Lyon.
  $p foaf:name $n.
  $p dbo:birthDate $birthDate.
  filter($birthDate > "1980-01-01"^^xsd:date).
  bind(replace(str($birthDate),"(\\d+)-\\d*-\\d*", "$1") as ?year)
  filter(xsd:integer(?year) > 1980)
}
```

Note, it might fail for other kinds of ill-formed dates. I didn't check all corner cases.

Somebody should report this to the DBpedia community. It should be fixed.